# SQL Query to get All the students id whose mark is greater than previous exam

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables **student** and **studentlastmarks**, the schema of both is as follows :

**student** table has following column : studentid, marks.

**studentlastmarks** table has : studentid, studentname, marks.

I need to get student id whose marks is greater than maximum marks of them in studentlastmarks table.

For Example :
Follwing are data in the student table :

```
studentid           studentname            marks
1                    krishna                60
2                    shiva                  70
3                    Arjun                  50
4                    Karna                  65
```

Following are data in studentlastmark table

```
studentid            marks
1                      65
2                      65
2                      50
3                      70
3                      60
4                      40
```

In this example we need to return student id 2 and 4 , since the marks obtained by the **student** in student table is greater than maximum marks obtained by particular student in **studentlastmarks** table.

I have tried the following code which gives max marks in whole studentlast marks table, but i need to compare it with max score of each student in **studentlastmarks** and **student** table

```
select distinct s.studentid from student as s where s.marks > (select max(sl.marks) from studentlastmarks as sl)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Find max. mark in studentlastmarks in subquery, then join and compare.

Comment: @shree.pat18 I tried with this select distinct s.studentid from student as s  where 
 s.marks > (select max(sl.marks) from studentlastmarks as sl)  Its giving me student who has marks greater than max of whole of studentlastmark. But i need max marks with respect to each of student.

Comment: Please remember to always include the code you have tried in your question itself. You can edit the question to add more information rather than putting it in comments, so that it is easier to see

Comment: Does the students not present in studentlastmarks must be returned?

Comment: @Akina No, student id should be shown whose max marks is studentlastmarks table is greater in student table mark. For example shown here max mark of student id 2 in studentlastmarks table is 65 and in student table he has marks 70, which is greater than his marks in studentlastmarks, so we need to select that ID, similar for student id 4 also

Comment: Note that in the real world, it would be unlikely to structure the data this way

Comment: Yes @Akina, student not present in studentlastmarks should be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
select s.studentid
From student s
Left join 
(Select studentid, max(marks) as maxmarks
  From studentlastmarks
  Group by studentid) lm 
On s.studentid = lm.studentid
Where s.marks > lm.maxmarks or lm.maxmarks IS NULL
```

The important bit is to group by student ID in the last marks table, so that you can compare on a per student basis.

EDIT: Based on your updated requirement to also show students not in last marks, we can use a LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN, and move the filter condition to a separate WHERE clause. The extra check for lm.maxmarks being null ensures that students not present in last marks table are included in the final result

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM student st
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM studentlastmark sm
                   WHERE sm.studentid = st.studentid
                     AND sm.marks > st.marks );
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=52c21318eee5af1ac764dbf4d2f9dca6

Indices by `(studentid, marks)` in both tables will improve.